# Samsung Magician Not Detecting EVO 870 Plugged in from SATA to USB

Tags: samsung-ssd, data-migration, sata-to-usb, samsung-magician

I bought a 1TB Samsung EVO 870 SSD on November 2022. I'm finally getting around to swapping it with my 500GB EVO 850 since I need more space anyways. I am trying to do data migration from my 500GB to my 1TBSSD. I downloaded the latest version of Samsung Magician and bought an Inland SATA to USB adapter.

When opening Samsung Magician, it will detect the new SSD but shows no data about it and when I click data migration or refresh, the drive disappears and I don't see the drive even after refreshing again. I am not able to see the drive on Device Manager or Disk Management either. When I unplug and replugin the drive, it will show back up on Samsung Magician but disappears again after refreshing. I am also able to see the drive in UEFI, but it struggles to show up in Windows.

Comment: *Inland SATA to USB adapter* This is problematic already. for starters. And Magician wasn't designed to work wit USB connected drives anyway. That said, if the adapter is this one https://www.amazon.com/Inland-Combo-Drive-Adapter-08412/dp/B001JQMEBM/ref=cm_cr_arp_d_product_top?ie=UTF8 or similar then 1. it's pure CRAP and 2. it probably isn't providing enough power as its main usage is with bigger SATA (or IDE) drives with an additional external power supply.

Comment: Don't you have an additional SATA port internally that you can use? There's NO motherboard where it makes sense to use (overpriced) SSDs with only one SATA port.

Comment: @ChanganAuto Well I bought the adapter at MicroCenter, in person. I thought an adapter came with the new SSD so that's why I didn't buy online. I wasn't expecting to get a bad product. I'll read about the product and see if it really is trash. I did wonder how it was suppose to deliver enough power through a USB cable.

Comment: @ChanganAuto My other SATA ports are actually taken by other drives.  One of which is a 1TB EVO 860 I added for more storage. I guess I can temporally unplug my DVD drive for a while for the new SSD

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out the Inland SATA to USB adapter that I bought turned out to be no good. Looking this item up on microcenter.com (Micro Center is where I bought the item in person), https://www.microcenter.com/product/485230/inland-usb-32-gen-1-to-25-sata-iii-hard-drive-adapter, I found this item had a lot of bad reviews and it was basically junk.

My solution was to put the EVO 870 in the case and borrow the SATA and power cable from my DVD drive for the SSD temporarily. When powering the computer back on and opening Samsung Magician, the program was able to detect the device and it was able to perform data migration to that drive. After that, I took out the SSD I was going to replace and installed the new one, gave back the DVD drive it's cables, and turned it back on. Computer runs fine, at least for now.